# Arithmetic keys on numeric keyboar android

Tags: android, math, input, android-edittext, keyboard

I have an edit text with:

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

This presents a keyboard that has numbers, but I need an edit text that lets me input arithmetic strings. For example, 5+3-2*4/4.

Please help.